# How do I do a sum in python for n+(n+12)+(n+24)+(n+36) and then for (n+1)+(n+13)+(n+25) and so on until reaching n+12?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

So lets say I have monthly data and I am trying to find a type of monthly change but the monthly change I want would be the following having this data frame the one I have is much bigger having every month from 2010 to 2019.

```
axis   Month Date    Value
1       1-2012        10 
2       2-2012        11
3       3-2012        15 
4       1-2013        12
5       2-2013        13
6       3-2013        17
7       1-2014        15
8       2-2014        16
9       3-2014        20
```

I want to arrive to an output such as

```
axis  value_sum  
1.    37 
2.    40 
3.    52
```

`1.which is equal as the sum of axis(1+4+7)
 2.which is equal as the sum of axis(2+5+8)
 3.which is equal as the sum of axis(3+6+9)`

so at the end I will have just 12 numbers as an output. 
Iv been trying to do this as with `def` and defining a function but when getting to this part I simply dont know what to do.

I actually am pretty new with managing data frames with python/pandas so I would appreciate the help.

Comment: How do you get the float output you posted? None of the numbers in your sample df equal 1.37

Comment: whats the dtype of your `month-date` do `print(df.dtypes)` to find out, also what are you summing exactly, the entire row, including the datetime?  or the value column?

Comment: G.Anderson  the 1 its just the appendix the actual value is 37 and its the sum of 10,12,15 which would sum to 37

Comment: Datanovice I just wan to sum the value column the date was just as a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'Month Date' is a string, group by quarter (extracted by `.str[:1]`) and sum:

`df['Value'].groupby(df['Month Date'].str[:1]).sum()`

If first part is a month (can be two digit):

`df['Value'].groupby(df['Month Date'].str.split('-').str.get(0)).sum()`

Comment: wouldn't this just sum quarters instead of like every year the sum of that month in the year?

Comment: @PandasINC I'm not sure I understand the difference. It will sum over whatever the first part of the 'Month Date' represents

Comment: Sorry my bad thank you, yeah yeah you are right thanks